# Validating Mongoose Mixed schema type

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema:

```
// Schema
var Product = new Schema({
  data: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    'default' : Date.now
  }
});
```

The 'data' field is used to store a json string which will vary. I do however want to perform some basic validation such as length etc.. However doing this:

```
// Validation
Product.path('data').validate(function (value) {
  console.log(value);
  return value.length > 0;
}, 'Data cannot be blank');
```

Throws an error about data not existing:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: data: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true }
~ doesn't that work?

Answer (score 3):

You are treating "value" as an object without checking if it really is. Try with this:

```
if(typeof value !== "undefined" && value !== null)
{
  return value.length > 0
}
```

Comment: Or just:  `return value && value.length;`